# Use dns suffixes only on certain wireless networks?

Tags: wireless-networking, dns, dhcp

quick question. I'm a software guy and networking is all black magic to me!

I have a laptop which I use at home and at the office. In order to be able to more easily reference our servers at work, I have our domain name in the DNS suffixes on my TCP/IP settings on my wireless connection. This all works beautifully and I can reference our servers simply by name only.

Now the problem... When I go home, it still has those suffixes in there, and I cannot access other servers because it appends the DNS suffixes to the server names.

Is there a way I can set up DNS suffixes so that they are only applied when connected to a certain wireless network (I'm thinking by SSID).

**EDIT:** After akira's answer I asked at the office about this idea, and found further information. Our DHCP is handled not by an actual "server" box, but by our Sonicwall firewall. I guess I would need to see if Sonicwall has any way to hand out DNS suffixes. I'll have to research that; if anyone has any idea about this, it'd be appreciated too.

Comment: so, whats the state of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the dns suffix should be supplied by the dhcp-server and thus change if you switch networks. if you manually assign dns suffixes: your fault. if the dhcp-server you use are not sending suffixes: either your fault or the fault of the admin of your company.

Comment: Sonicwall does have a way to do this (though it's hard to find, with no help from manuals, and needed a post to serverfault). After doing this found out our wireless network actually hands out DHCP from the wireless router while the wired network gets it from Sonicwall. So had to put this in the wireless router too, ... then all was beautiful.